# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.utils._pytree'

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

I have installed PyTorch 1.7.1, and it works very well. However, when I try to run this code:

```
import transformers
from transformers import BertTokenizer
from transformers.models.bert.modeling_bert import BertModel,BertForMaskedLM
```

I have got:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.utils._pytree'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try installing an earlier version of the transformers package.
`pip install transformers==4.28.0` worked for me.

Comment: I had transformers==4.36.0 and I depreciated it. That worked for me.